# Resend account activation email with django redux

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I've set up a registration system using Django registration-redux but I'm wondering if it's possible to resend account activation emails should the user not get one, have a problem receiving it or just lose it. I read this on the [redux FAQ docs](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) which suggests probably not:

> Assuming you’re using the default backend, a custom admin action is provided for this; in the admin for the RegistrationProfile model, simply click the checkbox for the user(s) you’d like to re-send the email for, then select the “Re-send activation emails” action.

but wondering if anybody else has this issue and resolved it somehow without requiring admin intervention? Seems like a thing you'd want to enable users to do (login and then click resend activation email since they can login even without being 'active') without having to email the admin straight away. TIA you awesome people.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a new boolean field to your user model (lets call it mail_sent) and after sending the registration email. You can set it to true.
Then put a middleware and check the incoming users email. If user is not verified but mail_sent is true. redirect the user to a url and let him/her to resend the activation email.